# How to receive just one line from an IO::Socket::Async in Raku?

Tags: raku

So, I have this:

```
    my $conn = await IO::Socket::Async.connect('127.0.0.1', 12340);  
    $conn.print: "GET /rest HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
```

How to receive just the first line from the server ?

I could use `whenever` and put some logic in it, but there's a simpler way, right ?

Comment: It's not the question but: `await` the `$coon.print`, otherwise you'll miss any errors.

Comment: .oO ( Discern and unify concern and compassion, action and wu wei, control and communication, and all is effortless )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really only want the first line, and don't care about the rest of the response, then you can do this:

```
my $first-line = await $conn.Supply.lines.first;
```

That is, get the `Supply` representing the response stream, have it split into lines (which results in a `Supply` of lines), and take the first line that arrives. Any data received beyond the first line will be discarded.

`IO::Socket::Async` works in terms of providing packets of data as they arrive. It doesn't get into providing a line-oriented interface; if a protocol really is so simple as reading line by line, then a `react whenever $conn.Supply.lines -> $line { }` will do it (and handles lines split over packets correctly).